# Possible to render *all* errors for a Field in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is it possible to get the *entire list* of errors for a `<Field />` with multiple validations?

From what I've read/seen the store only updates with a single error at a time.

I'd like to render a list of all validations for a given `Field` and update the color of each depending on if it's passing or failing. For instance:

***First Name***:
[ Greg ]
 - *Required (green)*
 - *Begins with capital (green)*
 - *Min length 5 (red)*

I understand the library provides this default behavior of passing a *single error* at a time:

***First Name***:
[ ]
 - *Required (red)*

...

***First Name***:
[ gr ]
 - *Begins with capital (red)*

...

***First Name***:
[ Greg ]
 - *Min length 5 (red)*

but this is not what I need. Would it be possible to render the **first** example with redux-form? Thanks for any info!

Comment: Displaying all errors shouldn't be a problem as errors are merely strings, thus you can concatenate any number of them and display accordingly. It should be more tricky to display passing validation rules.

Comment: `throw new SubmissionError` with all of your errors, not just the first one.